# Subclassing a UIButton programmatically?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I have a UIButton inside of an array which I would like to subclass to a SpringButton (https://github.com/MengTo/Spring). I tried this:

```
let springButton = playableCards[cardIndex] as! SpringButton
```

But I get this error:

Could not cast value of type 'UIButton' (0x1126bf120) to 'Spring.SpringButton' (0x10e6e62e8).

I do not want to create outlets or changing it in Storyboard. Is this a error from Swift, or an error from the pod itself?

Any help is welcome!

Edit:

```
var playableCards: [UIButton] = []
playableCards = self.allPlayableCardsViews[0].allSubviews.flatMap { $0 as? UIButton }
```

Where allPlayableCardsViews is just a regular UIView.

Comment: How is `playableCards` declared and created? Casting doesn't magically change an object from one type to another. It has to be a valid cast. It has to be that object type already.

Comment: Ok, I hope I added enough information. In Storyboard it is easy, just change the class to SpringButton. I thought the same concept would apply when casting it programmatically. Thanks for your help.

Comment: This doesn't show how the buttons are actually created. Are they actually created as `UIButton` instances or as `SpringButton` instances?

Comment: The buttons are created in Storyboard. The are inside of a UIView called allPlayableCardsViews. They are UIButtons. Or is this not what you mean?

Comment: I think the term you want is "downcast" rather than "subclass". Subclassing means creating a new class in your code that inherits from another class, but you're using a class from a library.

Comment: If your storyboard class is `UIButton`, it will be a `UIButton` and you can not cast it to a `SpringButton`. You need to put the actual class in the storyboard if they are created in the storyboard. Or you can create the buttons programmatically (as `SpringButton` instances) and not have them in the storyboard at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the class of the item in your storyboard scene is `UIButton` then the object *is* a `UIButton` and you can't simply downcast it as something else.  If you want your buttons to be `SpringButton`s, and they are being created by a storyboard scene, then you need to set the custom class *in the storyboard*.

Since `SpringButton` is a subclass of `UIButton` you can pass a `SpringButton` anywhere a `UIButton` is expected. You can also downcast a variable of type `UIButton` to a `SpringButton` as long as the underlying object *is* a `SpringButton`. Conditional downcasts with `as?` are safer than forced downcasts as you have found.

Imagine you have a parking space. Vehicles can park in the space. Motorcycles and cars are both types (subclasses if you will) of vehicle, so either can park there. But whether a vehicle is a car or a motorcycle is determined when it is built. You can't simply convert a motorcycle to a car by saying so later, but this is what you are trying to do with your buttons.